# "TypeConverter cannot covnert from System.String" in DialogOpenedAttached

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, material-design-in-xaml

I have a WPF project in .NET Core 3.0 and I'm using [MaterialDesignInXAML](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML)

I'm trying to show a dialog with a caledar (DatePicker) with a button click : [example](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MainDemo.Wpf/Pickers.xaml) (row 119)

The problem is when I write `materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogOpenedAttached="examlpetest"` it gives me the error *TypeConverter cannot covnert from System.String (code XDG0062)* so when I do

```
DialogOpenedAttached="
```

it doesn't automatically writes the hint to create the function.

Comment: Is material design in xaml compiled to Net core 3.0?  Do you realise that this version goes out of support very soon and 3.1 is the one with long term support?

Comment: @Andy 1) I have not found the answer in the xaml material design website so I dont know for sure.
2) Yes I know but I started this project with 3.0 destination..

What do you recommend to solve the problem?

Comment: I suggest you download the uncompiled source and look at what it is targetting. Maybe you can just re-target net core and it'll work better. I don't follow why you're "stuck" with net core 3.0.  Why not just use your project property page to target 3.1 instead? You can't have distributed this yet so I don't follow where the  issue would be.

Comment: @Andy I changed to 3.1 and nothing changed (MaterialDesignToolkit exampe is targetting 3.0).. other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: My suggestion was not just to change it to 3.1. I already made another suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself by changing `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>` to `<TargetFrameworks>net472;netcoreapp3.0</TargetFrameworks>` in the project file.